# Inference speed isn't improved with tensor-rt compared to regular cuda

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorrt, tensorrt-python

I'm trying to use the tensor-rt framework to enhance the inference speed of my deep learning model. I've created a very simple python code to test tensor-rt with pytorch.

```
import torch
import argparse
import time
import numpy as np
import torch_tensorrt

# Define a simple PyTorch model
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu1 = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu2 = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(64 * 16 * 16, 512)
        self.relu3 = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(512, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 16 * 16)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

def compute(use_tensorrt=False):
    force_cpu = False
    useCuda = torch.cuda.is_available() and not force_cpu
    if useCuda:
        print('Using CUDA.')
        dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor
        ltype = torch.cuda.LongTensor
        device = torch.device("cuda:0")
    else:
        print('No CUDA available.')
        dtype = torch.FloatTensor
        ltype = torch.LongTensor
        device = torch.device("cpu")

    model = MyModel()

    input_shape = (8192, 3, 32, 32)

    if use_tensorrt:
        model = torch.compile(
            model,
            backend="torch_tensorrt",
            options={
                "truncate_long_and_double": True,
                "precision": dtype,
                "workspace_size" : 20 << 30
            },
            dynamic=False,
        )

    model = model.to(device)
    model.eval()

    num_iterations = 100
    total_time = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        input_data = torch.randn(input_shape).to(device).type(dtype)
        #warmup
        for i in range(100):
            output_data = model(input_data)

        for i in range(num_iterations):
            start_time = time.time()
            output_data = model(input_data)
            end_time = time.time()
            total_time += end_time - start_time
    pytorch_fps = num_iterations / total_time
    print(f"PyTorch FPS: {pytorch_fps:.2f}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Without TensorRT")
    compute()
    print("With TensorRT")
    compute(use_tensorrt=True)
```

Unfortunately, when I run this code, I get approximately the same FPS with tensor-rt and without, which is ~14.2, even with a significant warmup. Does anyone know what could be the issue ? Is there something I'm missing ?

Here are some more information about my setup:

libraries:

```
torch 2.0.1
torch_tensorrt 1.4.0
```

GPU:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.119
Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30672275_0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `torch.compile` was first released in PyTorch 2.0, most of it was still experimental and wasn't documented very thoroughly.

I have absolutely no idea why your implementation doesn't work, but you get the desired improvement by using `torch_tensorrt.compile` instead of `torch.compile`.

```py
    input_shape = (8192, 3, 32, 32)
    inputs = [torch.randn(input_shape).to(device)]

    if use_tensorrt:
        model = torch_tensorrt.compile(
            model,
            inputs=inputs,
            workspace_size = 20 << 30,
            enabled_precisions = {torch.float},
        )
```

On my system with the same library versions, this yields a 3x improvement

```
>>> Without TensorRT
>>> Using CUDA.
>>> PyTorch FPS: 12.75
>>> With TensorRT
>>> Using CUDA.
>>> PyTorch FPS: 42.96
```

If I had to guess, it probably has something to do with `torch.compile` failing with the options provided, and defaulting to some other IR.